# How to call a function after CSS transition is finished - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css-transitions, settimeout

I have a React app that has a grid of cards. I added some javascript along with CSS transitions to animate the card flipping. When clicked, the card will flip to the back, wait 2 seconds then automatically flip back to the front.
This is my code. `isQuestionAnswered` and `isCorrect` are props passed down from the parent component.

```
const [isFlipped, setIsFlipped] = useState(false);
const [trigger, setTrigger] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
    if (isFlipped || !trigger) return;
    updateScore(points);
  }, [isFlipped]);

  function flipCard() {
    if (!isQuestionAnswered || !isCorrect) return;
    setIsFlipped(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setTrigger((prevState) => prevState + 1);
      setIsFlipped(false);
    }, 2000)
  }
```

I want to run the `updateScore()` function (another prop) after the transition is finished (so after the card is flipped back to the front). However, the `updateScore()` function will run immediately after the `isFlipped` state is set back to false. The `updateScore()` function then sets `isQuestionAnswered` to false before the flip transition (which takes 0.8s to finish) can even happen. How do I make it so I can run the `updateScore()` function after the transition is complete?

I've tried not having the `useEffect` hook and `trigger` state and just running the `updateScore()` inside the timeout within the `flipCard` function. I've also tried using a `setTimeout` inside `updateScore()` to set `isQuestionAnswered` to true after an .8 second delay (the time it takes for the transition to happen), but neither of those approaches worked.

Here is the current `updateScore()` function:

```
function updateScore(points) {
    setScore((prevState) => prevState + points);
    setIsQuestionAnswered(false);
  }
```

Comment: Have you looked into `animationend` event? Also, explcitly managing all necessary timings in js code *should* work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick answer: You can use [`onTransitionEnd`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/transitionend_event) or [`onAnimationEnd`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animationend_event), note how we are using the React names.

### Explanation

First we create a new state to save our timeoutId. This is good practice, just in case a user navigates away from the page we want to cancel the timeout.

```js
const [savedTimeoutId, setSavedTimeoutId] = useState(0)
```

Then we modify `flipCard` function to clear old timeouts before it starts, then it will set the `savedTimeoutId` by returning it to the dispatch function. Read more at [Updating state based on the previous state - React](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#updating-state-based-on-the-previous-state).

We also modify our [useEffect](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect) to have cancel the timeout if we dismount the component before we can flip back to the front.

```js
  const [savedTimeoutId, setSavedTimeoutId] = useState(0)
  function flipCard() {
    // if (!isQuestionAnswered || !isCorrect) return;
    setIsFlipped(true);
    setSavedTimeoutId((prev) => {
      // if we already have a timeout, cancel it
      if (prev !== 0) clearTimeout(prev);
      // start a new timeout and set it to savedTimeoutId
      return setTimeout(() => {
        setIsFlipped(false)
      }, 2000)
    })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    // if we move away from this page before we flip back to the
    // front, properly dispose of the setTimeout
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(savedTimeoutId);
    }
  }, [savedTimeoutId])
```

Finally attach some functionality `onTransitionEnd` to updateScore when we are flipping to the front

```
  return (
    <>
      <span>Score</span>
      <span> {score}</span>
      <br />
      <button
        className="test"
        onClick={() => {
          // setIsFlipped((prev) => !prev);
          flipCard(true);
        }}
      >
        Flip Card
      </button>
      <div
        className={isFlipped ? "flipped card" : "card"}
        onTransitionEnd={() => {
          // Only update score after flipping to front
          if (!isFlipped) {
            // can easily swap for updateScore function or anything else
            setScore(score + 1);
          }
        }}
      >
        Card Front
      </div>
      <div className={!isFlipped ? "flipped card" : "card"}>Card Back</div>
    </>
  );
```

Just be aware, each time `flipCard()` runs, it will reset the timer (because it cancels the old timeout and creates a new one). Modify as needed.

### [View demo at CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-demo-forked-873dwm?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: You are a lifesaver! This was beautifully explained